# syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ')' in opencart when clicking on customer

Tags: opencart2.x

No idea what it means as am not a developer. I do have access to a HTML editor (DW) so could change if told what to do.

I get this error when I click on customer in my admin Opencart.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ')' in /var/sites/p/proteinporridgewales.co.uk/public_html/cart/admin/controller/customer/customer.php on line 1105`

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste line 1105 please :)

Answer (score 4):

Its a mistake in `opencart 2.2.0.0`. THey have updated their master repository. You can also do this directly. Here is the solved line 1105 of `admin/controller/customer/customer.php`

Replace with this line

`} elseif (($custom_field['type'] == 'text' && !empty($custom_field['validation']) && $custom_field['location'] == 'address') && !filter_var($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => $custom_field['validation'])))) {`

You can visit **[this](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/4106)** for more details.

Answer (score 2):

parentheses in the wrong place ... change

```
!empty($custom_field['validation'] && $custom_field['location'] == 'address'))
```

to

```
!empty($custom_field['validation']) && $custom_field['location'] == 'address')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the problem, it is the problem with the "else if" part on error line 1105, which I have removed, just have lived the if statement leaving the closing brackets.

so that I have get rid of the error and can able to see the customer page.